# Не выводит значение в файл, но выводит на экран

Tags: c++

Нужно, чтобы значение answer выводило в файл, но выводит на экран совершенно другое значение, которое не должно получаться. Скорее всего из-за предупреждения в 60 строке:
"Предупреждение C6201   Индекс "1" находится вне диапазона от "0" до "0" для буфера "total", возможно, размещенного в стеке."
Сам код:

````
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int readdata() {
    int n;
    bool can[3][3];
    string s;
    std::cin >> n;
    for (int u = 1; n <= 3; u++) {
        std::cin >> s;
        int s2 = stoi(s);
        for (int p = 1; s2 <= 5; p++) {
            if (s[p] == 'Y') {
                can[u][p] = true;
                can[u][p] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return n;
}

int findcode() {
    const int magic[3][3] = { {1, 2, 3}, {2, 8, 16}, {4, 16, 32} };
    int code;
    bool can[3][3];
    code = 0;
    for (int u = 1; u <= 3; u++) {
        for (int p = 1; p <= 3; p++) {
            if (can[u, p]) {
                code = code + magic[u][p];
            }
        }
    }
    return code;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    const int magic[3][3] = { {1, 2, 3}, {2, 8, 16}, {4, 16, 32} };
    int n{}, code{};
    bool can[3][3];
    float total[1][3][63];
    float answer;
    string filein, fileout;

    system("cls");
    std::cout << "Введите путь, откуда будут браться данные" << endl;
    std::cin >> filein;
    std::cout << "Введите путь, куда будут сохраняться данные" << endl;
    std::cin >> fileout;
    ifstream input(filein);
    readdata;
    findcode;
    for (int u = 1; u <= 3; u++) {
        total[1][u][0] = 1;
    }
    for (int u = 2; u <= n; u++) {
        for (int p = 0; p <= 63; p++) {
            for (int k = 1; k <= 3; k++) {
                total[u % 2][k][p] = 0;
                for (int l = 1; l <= 3; l++) {
                    if (magic[k, l] && p != 0) {
                    total[u % 2][k][p] = total[u % 2][k][p] + total[1 - u % 2][l][p];
                    total[u % 2][k][p] = total[u % 2][k][p] + total[1 - u % 2][l][p] - magic[k][l]; }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    answer = 0;
    for (int u = 1; u <= 3; ++u) {
        answer = answer + total[n % 2][u][code];
    }
    std::ofstream out;
    out.open(fileout);
    if (out.is_open()) {
        std::cout << answer << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Где соответствующее правилам *желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения*? :( Из вашего вопроса непонятно, ни что программа должна делать, ни в чем именно проблема...

Comment: Первая строка входного файла содержит число N. (1 < N < 100). Следующие три строки входного файла, содержащие по три символа из набора {"Y", "N"}, соответствуют трем строкам диаграммы смежности. Других символов, включая пробелы, во входном файле не содержится. Входные данные корректны, т.е. диаграмма смежности симметрична.
А вывести в выходной файл количество полосок длины N, имеющих приведенную во входном файле диаграмму смежности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Беда кроется в этом куске кода:

```cpp
float total[1][3][63];

total[1][u][0] = 1;
```

Если Вы объявляете первый индекс массива `total` как N, то это означает, что в дальнейшем Вы можете использовать только те значения n, которые будут удовлетворять диапазону `0 <= n < N`. В данном случае у Вас `float total[1]...`, значит, первый индекс массива может быть только 0 (другие целые числа не входят в диапазон `0 <= n < 1`). Тем не менее, Вы в дальнейшем пишете `total[1]...`, т.е. пытаетесь вызвать несуществующий элемент массива со всеми вытекающими оттуда последствиями.

(Кстати, в других частях кода тоже подразумевается, что первый индекс может быть как 0, так и 1, что тоже ухудшает ситуацию).

Я предлагаю объявить массив как `float total[2][3][63]`, после чего указанная Вами проблема должна будет пропасть

Comment: Да, проблема и в правду исчезла. Только вот ошибка, которая вылазит после выполнения не исчезла "Ошибка проверки во время выполнения #2 - Стек вокруг переменной 'total' был поврежден."

Comment: @VenDeks потому что происходит выход за пределы массива для второго и третьего индекса (так, второй индекс объявлен как 3, т.к. Вы можете обращаться к подмассиву исходного массива с индексами от 0 до 2 (но Вы местами обращаетесь с тройкой, что выходит за диапазон); третий индекс объявлен как 63 => диапазон = (0; 62), но у Вас есть вызов с 63, что тоже вынуждает выходить за пределы. Тут нужно тоже увеличивать в объявлении массива числа: с 3 до 4 и с 63 до 64 соответственно

Comment: Спасибо большое. Надеюсь дальше сам смогу что-то сделать. Ибо до сих пор выводит в консоль какую-то ахинею

Comment: Пожалуйста. Если у Вас будут какие-то проблемы с кодом и Вы не сможете решить их, то можете создавать отдельные вопросы касательно них (только если их уже ранее не было на RuSO + Вы уже пересмотрели все доступные методы в Интернете)